# Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'void'. in angular

Tags: angular

I want to execute filter after Promises return values, am getting values from service but cannot execute further.

filter,map nothing applies on it. What am doing wrong here or we cannot apply filter from returned service function.?
Any suggestion

Error: **Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'void'.**

This is my service.

```
loadUsers() {
    fetch('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
         }).then((data) => {
             this.values = data
             console.log(data);
         }).catch((ex) => {
             console.error('Error fetching users', ex);
    });
}
```

then in my component.ts

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.newService.loadUsers().filter(res => res.id == '1');
    }

    constructor(private newService: MyDataService) { }
}
```

Comment: return the promise in loadUsers

Comment: yep works @david

Answer (score 4):

Promises. The function `loadUsers()` contains a promise. You need to return the promise first:

```
loadUsers() {
  return fetch('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    this.values = data
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }).catch((ex) => {
    console.error('Error fetching users', ex);
  })
}
```

And then,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.newService.loadUsers().then(function(users) {
        users.filter(res => res.id == '1');
    })
}
```

loadUsers() returns a promise and not a value like a regular function. That means, loadUsers() takes time to complete. When it does, the promise object contains the now-resolved value. You can extract this value using `<Promise object>.then()` which takes a function as an argument. The arguments of the function that you pass to .then (users in this case), contains what you're looking for.

Comment: now this error **Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'**

Comment: again previous error **Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'void'.**

Comment: Ah, you need to return something from the loadUsers() function. `return data;` on line 8

Answer (score 1):

First of all your function loadUsers do not return anything, you should write: `return fetch('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/')...`, besides I'm not sure we promises have filter method. 
May be do this:

```
    loadUsers() {
  return fetch('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {
    this.values = data
    return data;
  }).catch((ex) => {
    console.error('Error fetching users', ex);
  })
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.newService.loadUsers()
            .then(res => {
               res.filter(res => res.id == '1');
            })

}
```

Comment: its returning values if am just invoke that function

Comment: please tell more that this method should return

Comment: ok even like this i have tried now the error is: **Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.**

Comment: did you add return fetch...?

Comment: is loadUsers really placed in newService? try to console.log(this.newService.loadUsers) is it really this method?

Comment: yeah that is in service

Answer (score 0):

continuation to other answers,your json response is `object` and filter is Array method. json response contains `value` property which is array of object. see the plnkr

```
export class App {
  loadUsers() {
  return fetch('https://api.icndb.com/jokes/')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((data) => {

    return data.value;
  }).catch((ex) => {
    console.error('Error fetching users', ex);
  })
}
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/fvQX5SqKJ8xIOU85VgEo?p=preview)

Comment: see in console window

Comment: if you want to display on UI will modify the plnkr

Comment: @PrasanthS :see the updated plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/fvQX5SqKJ8xIOU85VgEo?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161640/discussion-between-santosh-singh-and-prasanth-s).